# MVC5 FileNotFoundException: System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Why Am I getting this error with my MVC5 project? I already added System.Data.SqlClient 4.0.0-beta-23019 nuget package in mu project.json. Any suggestions?

Error message:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Why Nuget? This should be available from assembly references. Are you using Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: project.json and MVC5. How is this possible?

Comment: have you restored the nuget packages?